# How would I go about adding a download "button" in Swipebox?

Tags: php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have done the easy bit and actually added a "Download Image" anchor into the swipebox.js html and formatted it with the CSS to make it play properly with the caption/title.

My specific problem lies in trying to add in a new data attribute containing the naked directory url to the image file and using that info to append it to the href of my created anchor so that I can link to the original size for each image.

Most other JQuery lightboxes can do this, but I stuck myself with using Swipebox because it was easier at the time and now it is returning to bite me in the ass.

You can check out what I have done so far @ http://kazenracing.com/?page=1964_Griffith

It is not as pretty as some of my other sites, but people will want the larger images.

You can see I am using timthumb for both the thumbnails and the viewed image, so things will run a bit faster on slower connections and so I do not have to create three separate images "by hand". If I did not care about load times and if my customer did not care about load times I would just have the full image be the viewed one and just use timthumb for the thumbnails alone.

You can also see a data-href attribute ready to go on everything except the videos, which I have already accounted for.

**EDIT**:

What I tried to do before was add in a function inside the swipebox JS called "setDownload" and tried many ways to pull the data-href into the href of the Download anchor.

The last one I tried that worked but only for the first image was:

```
setDownload : function () {
                    $('a[data-href]').each(function() {
                        $('#swipebox-download').attr('href', $('.swipebox').attr('data-href'));
                    });
                },
```

I even tried following the logic of setTitle, but that got me nowhere.

**EDIT**: Okay, now it has become; Who has got a better idea than putting it in the title attribute? Like so:

```
title="Image Name &lt;a id=&quot;swipebox-download&quot; href=&quot;path/to/image.jpg&quot;&gt;Download&lt;/a&gt;"
```

It does accomplish what I want, but it just seems dirty and wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I got off my lazy ass and just figured it out the way I wanted it in the first place.

The big problem I had was wrapping my head around using data attributes.
After I got my head around it I pretty much monkeyed the code in using brutaldesign's already existing code for attributes. I even added an option to change the text of the download link in case it is used for something completely different.

Here is the beef of the code I added:

```
setDownload : function ( index ) {
                var datahref = null;

                $( '#swipebox-download' ).empty();

                if ( elements[ index ] !== undefined ) {
                    datahref = elements[ index ].datahref;
                }

                if ( datahref ) {               
                    $( '#swipebox-download' ).append( plugin.settings.downloadText );
                    $( '#swipebox-download' ).attr( "href", datahref );
                } else {
                    $( '#swipebox-download' ).hide();
                }
            },
```

All the changes are documented [here on Github.](https://github.com/Serosis/swipebox/compare/brutaldesign:master...master)

Well, I guess, thank you for not answering my question.

I found it way more fulfilling figuring it out on my own than having it handed to me.

Oh, and the forked project page is [here](https://github.com/Serosis/swipebox), if anyone would like to use it.

Comment: thanks for your effort. It will help many developers. I am trying to add remove image button in swipebox. Downloaded your code. I will get back to you if any help needed. Voted Up